# Is acceleration perpendicular to velocity?

Tags: vectors

[image]

According to this relation can we say that $v.\left(\frac{dv}{dt}\right) \{v.a\}$ is always zero?

Comment: It literally says the equation is true if length is constant

Comment: Your notation is hard to read. What do the curly brackets mean? Are you trying to ask whether $\mathbf{v} \mathbf{\cdot} \frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} = 0$, where $\mathbf{v} = \frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt}$ and $\mathbf{r}(t)$ has constant lenght? If so, it's not very hard to find counterexamples. What did you try?

Comment: I don’t see acceleration in the equation

Comment: If we interpret $\mathbf{r}$ as velocity, the boxed assertion says, "If a particle moves with constant speed, then its acceleration is perpendicular to its velocity." It does _not_ say acceleration is perpendicular to velocity without qualification.